# Need an Html5 video to autoplay with sound

Tags: wordpress, video, html5-video

I have a HTML5 video which I want to autoplay with sound. I tried looking it up but apparently the option is not allowed anymor. Is there an alternative available?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No. Autoplay with sound was abused by invasive ads so browsers disabled it. There is no alternative, if there was an alternative it would be used by the invasive ads and defeat the entire point of preventing it.